# using core.Resource in a Dart transformer leads to Build error

Tags: dart, dart-pub

i started with the simple_transformer example on how to write a simple Dart Pub Transformer [simple_transformer](https://github.com/dart-lang/barback/blob/master/example/simple_transformer/lib/transformer.dart).
This example defines the content to insert into files by specifying it in code

```
String copyright = "Copyright (c) 2014, the Example project authors.\n";
```

instead i wanted to use the new (Dart 1.12) [Resource class from the core package](https://api.dartlang.org/1.12.1/dart-core/Resource-class.html) in order to load this copyright message from a local file (lib/copyright.txt):

```
static Future<String> loadCopyright() {
  var copyrightRessource = new Resource("package:simple_resource_loading_transformer/copyright.txt");
  return copyrightRessource.readAsString();
}
```

While invoking this method from the main function works

```
main() {
  print('load copyright.txt');
  //this loads the resource as expected
  InsertCopyright.loadCopyright().then(
      (String code)=>print(code)
  );
}
```

, invoking it in the Transformer's apply-method fails when trying to transform another package (which is what Transformers are for). You'll get a

*Build error: Transform InsertCopyright on {your project} threw error: Load Error for "package:simple_resource_loading_transformer/copyright.txt": SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused*

**How do i make Resource work in a Pub Transformer? Or is this missing functionality that still should be added to Dart?**

**Update**

so here is the working solution based on the proposed usage of the Transform API

```
static Future<String> loadCopyright(Transform transform) {
  var copyrightAssetId = new AssetId('simple_resource_loading_transformer', 'lib/copyright.txt');
  return transform.readInputAsString(copyrightAssetId);
}
```

The Transform instance comes from the parameter of your Transformer.apply method.

Comment: Resource is experimental and might not work properly yet. Especially it trying to create a socket connection IMHO doesn't look to good.

Comment: _"Resource is experimental and might not work properly yet."_ so should i put this as a bug somewhere?

Comment: I guess so. github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues and please cross-link with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/dart-lang/barback/issues/65#issuecomment-142455056

> You should really be using the Barback Transform APIs to load assets anyway. That's what it's for.